# Displaying the info from a MySQL database onto a html table

Tags: php, html, database, html-table

Recently I have been building my first website and as it is my first time working with PHP and databases I am having trouble. I have been researching for an answer for over three hours now. After following several tutorials I cannot get the databases information to display inside the table on my webpage. The only items that appear are a table header and one blank row. Am I not connecting to the database or is it something else that has to do with my code? Below is the code from the PHP that is inside my html file.

```
<?php
        $connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
        mysql_select_db('jcsavage_initiumjobs');

        if(!$conmnection){
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT name, address, ages FROM companies     ORDER BY name");
    ?>

        <table id='company_tables' border='1' align='centre'>
        <tr> <th colspan='3'>Companies</th> </tr>
        <tr> <th>Name of Company</th> <th>Location</th> <th>Ages Accepted</th> </tr>

    <?php
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>
        <tr><td> <?php . $row['name'] . ?> </td><td> <?php . $row['address'] . ?> </td><td> <?php . $row['ages'] . ?> </td></tr>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
        </table>
    <?php
        mysql_close($connection);
    ?>
```

I also had a second question. What do the strings localhost and root mean? And why is the password blank? Any help is appreciated. If you need more information about my database, my website hoster, more code, or anything else, feel free to ask.

Comment: **Debug** `$result = mysql_query("SELECT name, address, ages FROM companies ORDER BY name") or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: spelled `!$connection` wrong in if statement. also the localhost is the address of the database, root is the user name you are connecting as and the password is blank if that user doesn't have a password. [`mysql_connect()`](http://www.php.net/mysql_connect)

Comment: I'd like to suggest looking at the [mysqli php object](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php). It's a much more intuitive method of connecting to a mysql database.

Comment: For your second question: In very short explanation localhost is the name of your host, your are using a host which works only on your PC. The root is the username for example: who uses the localhost/phpmyadmin. and the password is blank because you didn't set it.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
    <tr><td> <?php echo $row['name']; ?> </td><td> <?php echo $row['address']; ?> </td><td> <?php echo $row['ages']; ?> </td></tr>
<?php
    }
?>
```

$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');

`localhost` is the domain of the server that is hosting the database 'jcsavage_initiumjobs'

`root` is the MySQL userid that you are connecting to MySQL server with.

`''` is the password, which in this case has not been set. When you set a password on the Userid 'root' you would add that instead of an empty (non existant) password

So for example if you set root's password to 'andBranch' you world code you connect as

```
 $connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'andBranch');
```

Comment: Thanks for responding so fast and for the clarification on the localhost and password. The information from the database however is still not showing up. This may be incorrect but at a guess I am thinking that the database may not be connecting for some reason, although I dont know much about php and databases.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<?php
    $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '','jcsavage_initiumjobs');
    if(!$connection){
        die("Could not connect:" . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
?>
<html>
<body>
<table id='company_tables' border='1' align='centre'>
<tr><th colspan='3'>Companies</th></tr>
<tr><th>Name of Company</th><th>Location</th><th>Ages Accepted</th> </tr>

<?php
$statement = "SELECT name, address, ages FROM companies ORDER BY name";
if($result = mysqli_query($connection, $statement))
{
  while($data = mysqli_fetch_object($result))
  {
    echo "<tr><td>$data->name</td><td>$data->address</td><td>$data->ages</td></tr>";
  }
}
?>
</table>
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: I have no clue why but it still isn't working. Inside the tables all that is printing out is $data-> and then what ever is there. I am also getting extra text "; } } ?>. I am not sure why this is appearing and I have looked almost everywhere. Is the username and password always supposed to be blank? Could it be something wrong with my database? Thanks for responding